# How can I use a combination or a string as an Index of DataFrame (Pandas)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use a combination of columns to create a new column in Pandas DataFrame. Since I did not know how to use  Combinations generated as indices I tried converting the combinations into string ,but that too is not working.

```
import itertools as iter
def pset(lst):
    comb = (iter.combinations(lst, l) for l in range(2,3))
    return list(iter.chain.from_iterable(comb))

temp = pset(transactions)
t = str(temp[0]).strip(" ")
transactions[[t]]
```

This is giving me an error

```
KeyError: '["\'A\', \'B\'"] not in index'
```

Here A and B are my columns in the dataframe.

```
transaction dataset:
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,0,1,1,0,1,1
1,1,1,1,0,1,0
1,0,0,1,0,1,0
0,0,1,1,1,0,0
1,0,0,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1

Expected output Expected output:
A,B  A,C  A,D
 1    2    4
```

Comment: Are you looking for pd.MultiIndex.from_product()?

Comment: I am performing apriori and I want to create an index combining multiple columns(indices) of same dataframe.

Comment: @YadyneshDesai - Can you add sample of dataframe : 5 - 6 rows and desired output?

Comment: @jezrael I have updated the question.The expected output is a small portion of what I actually want.

Comment: Thanks, but I am a bit confused - do you think all combination of columns `A, B, C, D, E, F, G` ? Can you explain more numbers `1 ,2,4` ?

Comment: @jezrael A B C D are column indexes.I am performing apriori algorithm where I want to count the occurences of combinations like (A,B) ,(B,C)  i e 2-itemset or even 3-itemsets like (A,B,C).
I want to create a pandas series which will have a sum for a particular combination.
In the above example A and B have occured just once together. 
Similarly A and C have occured twice together.
Basically I want to use the combinations generated as indexes of pandas series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get your expected output like this, `df` is the transaction dataset you posted. (This solution is made with Python 2.7 though, I hope it works the same in Python 3)

```
import itertools as iter
import pandas as pd

colComb = [a for a in iter.combinations(df.columns,2)]
newCols = [','.join(colComb[i]) for i in range(len(colComb))]

Out = pd.DataFrame(columns = newCols)
for i in range(len(colComb)):
    Out.loc[0,newCols[i]] = df[(df[colComb[i][0]] == 1) & (df[colComb[i][1]] == 1)][colComb[i][0]].count()
```

Output:

```
  A,B A,C A,D A,E A,F A,G B,C B,D B,E B,F B,G C,D C,E C,F C,G D,E D,F D,G E,F  \
0   1   2   4   1   4   1   2   2   1   2   1   4   2   3   2   3   5   2   2   

  E,G F,G  
0   1   2
```

Transpose if needed:

```
OT = Out.T
OT.columns = ["Count"]
```

Output:

```
    Count
A,B     1
A,C     2
A,D     4
A,E     1
A,F     4
A,G     1
B,C     2
B,D     2
B,E     1
B,F     2
B,G     1
C,D     4
C,E     2
C,F     3
C,G     2
D,E     3
D,F     5
D,G     2
E,F     2
E,G     1
F,G     2
```

EDIT:

Improved code to work with higher dimensions as well:

```
import itertools as iter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dim = 2
colComb = [a for a in iter.combinations(df.columns,dim)]
newCols = [','.join(colComb[i]) for i in range(len(colComb))]

Out = pd.DataFrame(columns = newCols)
for i in range(len(colComb)):
    Out.loc[0,newCols[i]] = df[np.sum(df[list(colComb[i])],axis=1) == dim][colComb[i][0]].count()
```

EDIT:

Much faster code for two dimensions:

```
cols = []
vals = []
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(df.columns)):
        cols.append(df.columns[i]+','+df.columns[j])
        vals.append(np.multiply(df[df.columns[i]],df[df.columns[j]]).sum())

Out = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
Out.loc[0] = vals
Out = Out.astype(int)
```

Another Edit, a faster solution to work with higher dimensions:

```
vals = []
colComb = [a for a in iter.combinations(df.columns,dim)]
cols = [','.join(colComb[i]) for i in range(len(colComb))]
vals = []
for C in colComb:
    v = df[C[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(C)):
        v = np.multiply(v,df[C[i]])
    vals.append(v.sum())
dd = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
dd.loc[0] = vals
dd = dd.astype(int)
```

It should work at least 3-4 time faster.

Comment: Thanks.I will try this in about two days and revert back.

Comment: In the above code is the dataframe index getting stored as a combination or a string?

Comment: If you do `OT = Out.T` and then look at `OT.index` you will see that the index is getting stored as strings. You can use `reset_index()` if you want those strings in a normal column and use a generic index instead.

Comment: It is taking a lot of time.

Comment: If your dataset is large it will take a lot of time.

Comment: Yes that is the problem.Is there any way I could do it faster?

Comment: I added two faster solutions, one for 2 dimensions, the second for arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: Ohhk I will try this and let you know

Comment: the solution you posted is taking more time than before

Comment: `dim=3
vals = []
colComb = [a for a in iter.combinations(transactions.columns,dim)]
cols = [','.join(colComb[i]) for i in range(len(colComb))]
vals = []
for C in colComb:
    v = transactions[C[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(C)):
        v = np.multiply(v,transactions[C[i]])
    vals.append(v.sum())
dd = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
dd.loc[0] = vals
dd = dd.astype(int)
print(dd)`

Comment: I'm suprised to hear that, but if your data is very large other factors might come into play that I did not feel when testing with your small example. I can't think of a faster method than using the highly optimized numpy routine `np.multiply` for the most time-consuming operation.

Comment: ohk no problem.currently I am using the first solution you sent.
What I am doing is getting the combinations, retrieving the letters from those combinations and creating a string index using those characters.
It is working pretty well upto 3 transactions but not very scalable I think

Comment: The formula for the number of combinations of a set of items involves factorials, so it really doesn't scale well.